# Installing Redis on CentOS 6.6 final - no package available

Tags: centos6, yum, redis, epel

I've added the "EPEL" repo:

```
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: repos.mia.lax-noc.com
 * epel: epel.gtdinternet.com
 * remi-safe: remi.xpg.com.br
 * rpmforge: mirror.rit.edu
repo id         repo name                                                   status
base            CentOS-6 - Base                                              6,518
elrepo          ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el6         333
epel            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64              11,743
extras          CentOS-6 - Extras                                               38
mongodb-org-3.0 MongoDB Repository                                              40
remi-safe       Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64      11
rpmforge        RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                  4,718
updates         CentOS-6 - Updates                                           1,370
zabbix          Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                            289
repolist: 25,060
```

But every time I run:

```
sudo yum install redis
```

I get this:

```
No package redis available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**NOTE:**
I've already ran:

```
sudo yum clean metadata
```

But still, can't install redis.

Comment: Did you exclude it?

Comment: No that I know. How can I check?

Comment: Look for exclude directives in yum.conf and in all the .repo files.

Comment: No, there is no such directive in any repo file nor yum.conf

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the EPEL repo?  Here's what works for me on CentOS 6.6-final

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
yum install redis -y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install redis
```

Comment: You need to install remi-release, not epel-release, which is already installed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum list redis
sudo yum install redis.x86_64  # something list before.
```

You could list the packages by yum list and then choose which to install.
You get package not available is because the name you type is not exist, so list before you install.